# Designing a schema for an entity with 40 attributes

Tags: mysql, database-design, eav

I am having a doubt on designing a schema for my current project in MySQL.

It is mainly because there is an entity that I made and has 40 attributes.

The table/entity X contain of fields like: collection of personal information, physical attributes (such as hair color, eye color, height, etc) mostly a varchar with less than 10 chars.

The question is:
Should I break the attributes into another table or let it stays in one table X with all those 40 attributes with it?

Answer (score 0):

Having a table with 40 columns is not an issue. Issue raises only how these attributes are getting updated provided there is no concurrent updates of the Attributes. Otherwise there will be an issue with locking.

Answer (score 0):

Designing : functional dependency should be a guide to be sure that all 40 attributes are i the same entity :

- your entity must have an identifier
- (all attributes must be atomics)
- all other attributes must be functionally dependent of the identifier

in other terms : for a unique value (occurrence) of the identifier, you must get one unique value of each of the other attributes.

If not, you should break your entity.

20 years ago, I had the same probleme with products and their caractéristics (100 or more). Below is the solution I used :

- Product (idp, ...important/frequent attributes) (idp) PK
- Caracteristic (idc, title, type of data) : (idc) PK
- ProductCaracteristics (idp, idc, numeric value, string value), (idp, idc) PK, (idp) FK to Product, (idc) FK to Caracteristics

It is evolutive but needs more data space.